# mysql wont start Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, apparmor

So MySQL won't restart/start after a server reboot. No configuration files have been edited / any changes made. 
I have the same problem as this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916009/mysql-wont-start-because-of-apparmor) where apparmor is causing these log entries:

```
Sep 27 11:18:53 staging audit[2986]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/2986/status" pid=2986 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=112
Sep 27 11:18:53 staging audit[2986]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=2986 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=0
Sep 27 11:18:53 staging audit[2986]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/2986/status" pid=2986 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=112
```

When these execptions are added to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` 
as :

```
# fix issue with mysql not restarting
  /proc/*/status r,
  /sys/devices/system/node/ r,
  /sys/devices/system/node/node0/meminfo r,
# Allow network access
```

Then as root : `service apparmor reload; service mysql restart;`

The logs now only display:

```
Sep 27 11:25:10 staging systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Sep 27 11:25:10 staging systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 27 11:25:10 staging systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 27 11:25:10 staging systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 27 11:25:10 staging systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Sep 27 11:25:10 staging systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Sep 27 11:25:11 staging systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

I have not made any configuration changes so I don't really know where else to look. I was going to reinstall MySQL, however, I have data that I don't have backed up :( pls help

Comment: I have tried to reinstall mysql-server but still have only one error : 'mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've managed to get it working although i don't know how this worked, but i ran:
`apt-get remove mysql*; apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client ;`
the first time i was still unable to start mysql. And then i ran it again and mysql has started to work again. I also was able to remove the lines:

`/proc/*/status r,
 /sys/devices/system/node/ r,
 /sys/devices/system/node/node0/meminfo r,`

from `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` and reloaded apparmor.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this for ubuntu 16.04 and up

```
  sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Comment: No difference in output or effect

Comment: mkdir /var/run/mysqld

,   touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock,  

chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld.  
then restart

Comment: I've seen this around but i'm not sure what this is meant to solve?

Comment: this is for create directory for mysql then permissions to this

Comment: I tried this but mysql is still not starting and just logging `mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE`